# Верстка 2-х колонок

Tags: html, css

Вот к примеру есть разметка:

```css
html,body,.container{
  height:100%;
}
.container{
  position:relative;
}
.main-nav{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  width:150px;
  background-color:green;
}
.main-content{
  background-color:blue;
   position:absolute;
  top:0;
  min-height:100%;
  left:150px;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-nav">Блок 1</div>
  <div class="main-content"><div style="height: 900px">Блок 2, длинный</div></div>
</div>
```

Почему из-за блока с классом `.main-content` не растягивается `.container`? Как его растянуть? Я так понимаю это из-за него блок `.main-nav` не соответствует высоте `.main-content`.

Comment: Потому что `position: absolute`

Comment: @andreymal, тут только js поможет?

Comment: поможет flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какой `position:absolute;` о чем вы думаете? сейчас используется flexbox.

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
  align-items:stretch;

}

.main-nav{

  min-height:100vh;
  width:150px;
  background-color:green;
}
.main-content{
  background-color:blue;
  flex: 1;
  min-height:100%;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-nav">Блок 1</div>
  <div class="main-content"><div style="height: 900px">Блок 2, длинный</div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
html,body,.container{
  height:auto;
}
.container{
  position:relative;
}
.main-nav{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  width:150px;
  background-color:green;
}
.main-content{
  background-color:blue;
  position:relative;
  top:0;
  min-height:100%;
  left:150px;
  right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="main-nav">Блок 1</div>
  <div class="main-content"><div style="height: 900px">Блок 2, длинный</div></div>
</div>
```